# Why first activity does not move to another one,emulator shows "Unfortunately,app has stopped but my Logcat doesn't show any errors"?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-activity, android-emulator

Android studio does not return me any errors but when I run this code emulator I receive a message `Unfortunately, the app has stopped`

I am connecting two activities in the android studio using OnClick and Intent. I tried to find errors through Logcat but even there, there are no any errors.

First page is `std_home.java` and second is `std_registration.java`

```
public class std_home extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button b2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_std_home);

        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.std_sign_in);
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                startActivity(new Intent(std_home.this, std_registration.class));
            }
    });




public class std_registration extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView t;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_std_registration);

        t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.reg_title);
        Typeface myCustomFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/AdobeMing-Light.ttf");
        t.setTypeface(myCustomFont);

    }
}
```

The expected result is after button `Sign in` is clicked app should open registration form but it stops the process with the message `Unfortunately, the app has stopped`.

Comment: If your app crashes then an exception with stacktrace is written to logcat. You should examine the logcat carefully when your app crashes. If you don't see anything it means that you are filtering the logcat and the filter is causing you to miss the exception logging. Disabled all logcat filters.

Comment: Add the manifest to your original post. The most likely reason your app stops when you try to launch another `Activity` is that you don't have that `Activity` declared in your manifest.